# How to get the value of a field from mongoDB using mongoose through javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is a document under the collection **users** in my database **newDb**,

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57025801593e301831ef3c72"),
        "country" : "U.S",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "lastName" : "Ks",
        "firstName" : "Balajee",
        "password" : "$2a$08$.Qts1uaOJiyH.A0LM9QeGOB1EBfItB2nV29RxLVbloDnzAggIuGf6",
        "email" : "balajee41@gmail.com",
        "position" : [
                "1",
                "2"
        ],
        "__v" : 1,
        "operation" : "add",
        "userip" : "11"}
```

How can I fetch **position,operation and userip** from this document and use it for executing a function?
This is a function in a separate Javascript file apart form the main node file.

```
function verifyOTP() {
    var position = user.position;
    var operation = user.operation;
    var useripp = user.userip;
    check(arr, position, operation, useripp);
}
```

Comment: What is `arr` here. Is it the result of the `find` method on the `users` collection?

Comment: No, arr is a global array in that javascript file,

Comment: Also i haven't exported anything in that JS file, it contains some form validation and submission

Comment: Can you export the method `check` from that JS file? Just the method `check` and nothing else.

Comment: yes, i can, now I did module.exports = function check(arr, position,operation,useripp)

Comment: You would also have to take the arr from the same JavaScript file. And not declare it as a parameter to the `check` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108209/discussion-between-balajee-ks-and-siddharth-ajmera).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Helper = require('path_to_the_module_where_the_method_check_is_defined_and_exported');

function verifyOTP(user) {
    var position = user.position;
    var operation = user.operation;
    var useripp = user.userip;
    Helper.check(position, operation, useripp);
};

var query = {
    // Your query here
};

var projection = {
     position: 1,
     operation: 1,
     userip: 1,
     _id: 0
};

User.findOne( query, projection, function(err, user) {
    if(err) console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    if(user) verifyOTP(user);
});
```

Comment: What will be in the Query? and i'm adding this to my route.js file under a post call

Comment: the field and the value you want to search the `users` collection on. For eg : `var query = { "firstName" : "Balajee" }` Would search on field `firstName` for value `"Balajee"`.

Comment: I'm getting db as undefined @Siddharth

Comment: Didn't know you were using Mongoose. Have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mongoose` it's much better to define model and work with it, than with raw collection.

First of all define a model in file `user.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  // TODO: add other required fields
});

mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

exports.userSchema = userSchema;
```

Add validation logic in `validation.js` for example:

```
exports.verifyOTP = function(user) {
  var position = user.position;
  var operation = user.operation;
  var useripp = user.userip;
  check(arr, position, operation, useripp); // TODO: what is arr?
};
```

And in `user-service.js`, add the following code:

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('user');
var validation = require('./validation');

var filter = { name: 'firstName' }; // TODO: use real filter here
var fields = 'position operation userip';
User
  .findOne(filter, fields)
  .then(validation.verifyOTP)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: actually, I'm in another JS(script.js) apart from the main node file (server,js is my case) which has no exports or links to the mongoDB or mongoose

Comment: And what the problem? Your project uses mongoose, right? Where do you connecting to db?

Comment: The JS file that I'm working on has some form validations and a function which takes the values of the fields in my database.

Comment: I'm having problem with applying filter. I've used _id as filter and I'm getting [ReferenceError: position is not defined] @Alexander

Comment: I shown you how to resolve your original issue. If you have a new issue, create a new question, add code and error description there.

Comment: Hi @alexander, I haven't defined user in validation.js file, which is why I'm getting the reference error. How do i define users in my validation.js file?